# Qt QTextEdit line numbers

Tags: c++, qt, code-editor

I'm working on a code editor for GLSL in Qt and I'm having problems with showing the line numbers of a QTextEdit. I undestand the example from [Qt Code Editor Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-codeeditor-example.html) but this part

```
QTextBlock block = firstVisibleBlock();
int blockNumber = block.blockNumber();
int top = (int) blockBoundingGeometry(block).translated(contentOffset()).top();
int bottom = top + (int) blockBoundingRect(block).height();
```

doesn't really combine well with a QTextEdit given the fact that I don't have the firstBisibleBlock, blockBoundingGeometry and blockBoundingRect methods. I know the blocks are kept in a QTextDocument but that class doesn't have these methods either.

I tried searching for an example but every time someone asks this question he is directed to that same link.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem and i got stuck in the same issue.

Comment: Here is working example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443358/how-to-add-lines-numbers-to-qtextedit